# Apache Spark tuning on distributed environment

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'd maximize Hadoop performance in a distributed environment (using Apache Spark with Yarn) and I'm following the hints on a [blog post of Cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) with this configuration:

```
6 nodes, 16 core/node, ram 64G/node
```

and the proposed solution is: 
`--num-executors 17 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 19G`

But i didn't understand why they use 17 num executors (in other words 3 executors for each node).

Our configuration is instead:

```
8 nodes, 8 core/node, ram 8G/node
```

What is the best solution?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but that article is a bit old. Take a look at dynamic resource allocation (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation) available since spark 1.2. When this feature is enabled, executors are being allocated/removed dynamically according to the needs of an application

Comment: which spark version did you use?

Comment: Spark version is 1.5.2, Hadoop 2.7.1

Comment: 8 core/node, is it 8 physical i7 cores, which would be 16 cores, or really 8 cores?

Answer (score 1):

Your ram is pretty low. I would expect this to be higher.

But, we start off with 8 nodes, and 8 cores. To determine our max executors we do nodes*(cores-1) = 56. Minus 1 core from each node for management.

So I would start off with 
56 executors, 1 executor core, 1G ram.

If you have out of memory issues, double the ram, have the executors, up the cores. 
28 executors, 2 executor cores, 2G ram
but your max executors will be less, because an executor must fit onto a node. You will be able to get a total of 24 allocated containers max.

I would try 3 cores before 4 cores next, as 3 cores will fit 2 executors on each node, while with 4 cores you will have the same executors as 7.

Or, you can skip right to...
8 executors, 7 cores, 7gig ram(want to leave some for the rest of cluster).

I also found if CPU Scheduling was disabled, yarn was overriding my cores setting, and it was always staying at 1, no matter my config. Other settings must also be changed to turn this on.

`yarn.schedular.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator`